# How to represent one-to-one relationship in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

Assume I have
sig A{}
sig B{e:A}
I want to represent 1-1 mapping between A and B so for each B there is one and only one A correspond to:

```
{all b:B | one a : A | b.e = a}
```

Are there some another way to do that, such as using multiplicity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write to ensure that each B is related to exactly one A :

```
 sig B{
   e: one A
 }
```

**Edit:**

To ensure that each A is related to exactly one B you can add a signature fact to the signature declaration of A

```
sig A{
}{
    one this.~e
}
```

**Why this work :**

The signature fact under signature A is processed by Alloy as:

```
fact{
    all a:A | one a.~e
}
```

in which:

- **e** is a field defined in signature B. It hence define a relation of type **B -> A**.
- The **~** operator yields the inverse of that relation (so the type becomes **A -> B** ).
- The "dot join" between **a** and that  relation (**A.A->B**) yields all the **B** elements for which **B.e=a**.
- The **one** keyword is finally used to say that there's only one such **B** element (for all a).

Comment: As I know, "e: one A" is equivalent to "e: A". But it cannot make sure all a:A referred by exactly one b:B

Comment: that was not clearly asked in the question, I updated my answer.

Comment: hello, I am having some troubles to understand why this worked. could you maybe elaborate a bit more? (I am still new to alloy and its syntax)